# Calculation downtime in minute start from '0' when the value bigger than 24 hour

Tags: php, laravel

I need to calculate downtime in minute based on **start date of business hour ,end date of business hour start date and end date**.The problem is when **my downtime value exceeds 24 hour** which in minute is **1440 minutes** , downtime value become start from '0' .

Let say my start date is **2021-09-01 09:00:00**

```
$startdateTimes = strtotime('2021-09-01 09:00:00');
```

End date is **2021-09-03 16:00:00**

```
$enddateTimes = strtotime('2021-09-03 16:00:00');
```

Start time Business Hour is 8:30

```
$bhStartTime = '8:30';
```

End time Business Hour 17:30

```
$bhEndTime = '17:30'
```

My full code

```
$startdateTimes = strtotime('2021-09-01 09:00:00'); //start date

                        $setdate12AM = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$startdateTimes));
                        $setdate12AM->setTime('0','0');
                        $setdate12AM->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $date12AM = $setdate12AM->getTimestamp();
                        
                        $bhStartTime = '8:30'; //biz hour start time
                        $bhStartSplit = explode(":",$bhStartTime); 
                        $setbhStartTimesDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$startdateTimes));
                        $setbhStartTimesDate->setTime($bhStartSplit[0], $bhStartSplit[1]);
                        $setbhStartTimesDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $bhStartTimes = $setbhStartTimesDate->getTimestamp();
                        
                        $bhEndTime = '17:30' //biz hour end time
                        $bhEndSplit = explode(":",$bhEndTime); 
                        $setbhEndTimesDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$startdateTimes));
                        $setbhEndTimesDate->setTime($bhEndSplit[0], $bhEndSplit[1]);
                        $setbhEndTimesDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                        
                        if(strtotime('12:00am') < strtotime($bhEndTime) && strtotime($bhStartTime) > strtotime($bhEndTime)){
                            $bhEndTimes = $setbhEndTimesDate->getTimestamp();
                            $bhEndTimes = strtotime("+1 day", $bhEndTimes);
                        }else{
                            $bhEndTimes = $setbhEndTimesDate->getTimestamp();
                        }
                        //----------------------------------------------

                        $enddateTimes = strtotime('2021-09-03 16:00:00'); //end date
                       

                        $setdate12AMEnd = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$enddateTimes));
                        $setdate12AMEnd->setTime('0','0');
                        $setdate12AMEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $date12AMEnd = $setdate12AMEnd->getTimestamp();

                        $bhStartSplitEnd = explode(":",$bhStartTime); //biz hour start time
                        $setbhStartTimesDateEnd = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$enddateTimes));
                        $setbhStartTimesDateEnd->setTime($bhStartSplitEnd[0], $bhStartSplitEnd[1]);
                        $setbhStartTimesDateEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $bhStartTimesEnd = $setbhStartTimesDateEnd->getTimestamp();

                        $bhEndSplitEnd = explode(":",$bhEndTime); //biz hour end time
                        $setbhEndTimesDateEnd = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$enddateTimes));
                        $setbhEndTimesDateEnd->setTime($bhEndSplitEnd[0], $bhEndSplitEnd[1]);
                        $setbhEndTimesDateEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                        if(strtotime('12:00am') < strtotime($bhEndTime) && strtotime($bhStartTime) > strtotime($bhEndTime)){
                            $bhEndTimesEnd = $setbhEndTimesDateEnd->getTimestamp();
                            $bhEndTimesEnd = strtotime("+1 day", $bhEndTimesEnd);
                        }else{
                            $bhEndTimesEnd = $setbhEndTimesDateEnd->getTimestamp();
                        }


                        if($startdateTimes >= $bhStartTimes && $startdateTimes <= $bhEndTimes){

                            $ExactStartDate = $startdateTimes; //start at incident start date


                        }else if($startdateTimes >= $bhEndTimes){
                            $ExactStartDate = strtotime("+1 day", $bhStartTimes); //add 1 day and start at 8.00am


                        }else if($startdateTimes <= $bhStartTimes && $startdateTimes >= $date12AM){
                            $ExactStartDate = $bhStartTimes; //start at 8.00am same date
                        }

                        if($enddateTimes >= $bhStartTimesEnd && $enddateTimes <= $bhEndTimesEnd){
                            $ExactEndDate = $enddateTimes; //end at incident end date
                        

                        }else if($enddateTimes >= $bhEndTimesEnd){
                            $ExactEndDate = $bhEndTimesEnd; //end at 6.00pm same date

                        }else if($enddateTimes <= $bhStartTimesEnd && $enddateTimes >= $date12AMEnd){
                            $ExactEndDate = $bhStartTimesEnd; //start at 8.00am same date
                        }
                        
                        
                        while($ExactStartDate < $ExactEndDate){

                            
                            $setdailyEndDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$ExactStartDate));
                            $setdailyEndDate->setTime($bhEndSplitEnd[0], $bhEndSplitEnd[1]);
                            $setdailyEndDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            //dd( $setdailyEndDate);
                            if(strtotime('12:00am') < strtotime($bhEndTime) && strtotime($bhStartTime) > strtotime($bhEndTime)){
                                $dailyEndDate = $setdailyEndDate->getTimestamp();
                                $dailyEndDate = strtotime("+1 day", $dailyEndDate);

                            }else{
                                $dailyEndDate = $setdailyEndDate->getTimestamp();
                                //dd( $setdailyEndDate);
                            }

                            if($dailyEndDate < $ExactEndDate){
                                $datediff = $dailyEndDate - $ExactStartDate;
                                $downTime += $datediff;
                           
                            }else{
                                $datediff = $ExactEndDate - $ExactStartDate;
                                $downTime += $datediff;

                               
                            }


                            $setdailyStartDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$ExactStartDate));
                            $setdailyStartDate->setTime($bhStartSplitEnd[0], $bhStartSplitEnd[1]);
                            $setdailyStartDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $dailyStartDate = $setdailyStartDate->getTimestamp();

                            $ExactStartDate = strtotime("+1 day", $dailyStartDate);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        

        $downTime = (gmdate('H', $downTime) * 60) +  (gmdate('i', $downTime)); //convert to minute , expected output '1500'
```

My expected **output is 1500 minutes** which in hour is 25 hour based on start/end date and start/end business hour....when i change my end date lower than 24 hour...the value is correct but up to 24 hour my value start from '0'

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? This sounds like a good exercise for test-driven development. Also, how is this related to Laravel - as far as I see you don't use any Laravel-related stuff in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing gmdate to floor

```
$downTime = (int)floor(($downTime / 60));
```